# DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION when im playing video games

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard, crash, bsod

I get this BSOD (DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION) while im playing games like CS:GO and GTA V on PC. I am playing for like 15minutes without any problems but then i suddenly get this error and my pc restarts.

**Specs:**
Corsair CX 750M, 750W PSUATX 12V V2.3, 80 Plus Bronze, Modular. 4x 6+2pin P

Intel Core i5-4670K Processor
Socket-LGA1150, Quad Core, 3.4GHz, 6MB, 84W, HD460

MSI Z87-G45 Gaming, Socket-1150
ATX, Z87, DDR3, 3xPCIe-x16, SLI/CFX, VGA,HDMI,DP,K

Cooler Master Seidon 120M CPU Kjøler
775/1150/1155/1156/1366/2011, AM2(+)/AM3(+)/FM1, 6

Crucial DDR3 BallistiX Sport 16GB KIT
16GB kit (8GBx2), Sport,1600MHz, 1.5V, CL9-9-9-24

Gainward GeForce GTX 770 2GB PhysX CUDA
PCI-Express 3.0, with Batman Arkham Origins

Kingston SSDNow V300 120GB 2.5" OEM
SATA3.0, 7mm, 450MB/450MB/s read/write, SandForce

**minidump from the most recent crash: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ccd6hhyh39fls6r/060415-14406-01.dmp?dl=0**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the dump](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks), the [DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj154556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) bugcheck is casued by your nVIDIA driver:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, A single DPC or ISR exceeded its time allotment. The offending
    component can usually be identified with a stack trace.
Arg2: 0000000000000501, The DPC time count (in ticks).
Arg3: 0000000000000500, The DPC time allotment (in ticks).
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for nvlddmkm.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for nvlddmkm.sys

SYSTEM_SKU:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  1.0

BIOS_DATE:  09/03/2013

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  Z87-G45 GAMING (MS-7821)

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  1.0

BUGCHECK_P1: 0

BUGCHECK_P2: 501

BUGCHECK_P3: 500

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

DPC_TIMEOUT_TYPE:  SINGLE_DPC_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: d48

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3c

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x133

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  d

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10069.9 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
02 nt!KeClockInterruptNotify
03 hal!HalpTimerClockInterrupt
04 nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine
05 nt!KiInterruptSubDispatchNoLockNoEtw
06 nt!KiInterruptDispatchLBControl
07 nt!KxWaitForSpinLockAndAcquire
08 nt!KeAcquireSpinLockRaiseToDpc
09 nvlddmkm


IMAGE_NAME:  nvlddmkm.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x133_dpc_nvlddmkm!unknown_function

Loaded symbol image file: nvlddmkm.sys
Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys
Image name: nvlddmkm.sys
Timestamp:        Thu May 28 04:49:51 2015 (5566824F)
```

Try different drivers, make sure the GPU doesn't overheat. Also update the BIOS, you still use the first BIOS from 2013.